# Read separately zipped csv file (.zip .z01 etc) over Python zipfile library

Tags: python, csv, python-zipfile

How could we read csv file which is zipped into multiple files?

Due to the 4 GB limit of FAT storage format, I have complied csv file into multiple zip files like `test.zip` and `test.z01`.

I found the library `zipfile` which can read csv file in the "single" zipped file. But I have no idea with reading a csv file in "separately" zipped file.

For example:
[Reading csv zipped files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942476/reading-csv-zipped-files-in-python)
provide how to read csv file in one zipped file.

```
import pandas as pd
import zipfile

zf = zipfile.ZipFile('C:/Users/Desktop/THEZIPFILE.zip') 
df = pd.read_csv(zf.open('intfile.csv'))
```

In summary, my question is that how can we read both `test.zip` and `test.z01` at the same time and access to the csv file?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in a roundabout way by explicitly making two csv file into completely different two zipped file which have similar number of columns and combline them into one file.

```
import pandas as pd
import zipfile

zf1 = zipfile.ZipFile('C:/Users/Desktop/THEZIPFILE1.zip') 
df1 = pd.read_csv(zf1.open('intfile.csv'))

zf2 = zipfile.ZipFile('C:/Users/Desktop/THEZIPFILE2.zip') 
df2 = pd.read_csv(zf2.open('intfile.csv'))
```