# Read multiple csv files zipped in one file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, zip

I have several csv files in several zip files in on folder, so for example:

- A.zip (contains csv1,csv2,csv3)
- B.zip (contains csv4, csv5, csv6)

which are in the folder path `C:/Folder/`, when I load normal csv files in a folder I use the following code:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
files = glob.glob("C/folder/*.csv")
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, header=None, sep=";") for f in files]

df = pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)
```

followed by this post: [Reading csv zipped files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942476/reading-csv-zipped-files-in-python)

One csv in zip works like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import zipfile

zf = zipfile.ZipFile('C:/Users/Desktop/THEZIPFILE.zip') 
df = pd.read_csv(zf.open('intfile.csv'))
```

Any idea how to optimize this loop for me?

Comment: [ZipFile.namelist()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist)` should give you list of all file inside .zip so you can use this list in `for-loop` to read .csv from .zip

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `zip.namelist()` to get list of files inside the zip

**Ex:**

```
import glob
import zipfile
import pandas as pd

for zip_file in glob.glob("C/folder/*.zip"):
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file)
    dfs = [pd.read_csv(zf.open(f), header=None, sep=";") for f in zf.namelist()]
    df = pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)
    print(df)
```

Comment: I have severals Zipfiles, not only one

Comment: In that case just loop the list of zip files first?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to tackle it in two passes. First pass, extract the contents of the zipfile onto the filesystem. Second Pass, read all those extracted CSVs using the method you already have above:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import zipfile

def extract_files(file_path):
  archive = zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, 'r') 
  unzipped_path = archive.extractall()
  return unzipped_path

zipped_files = glob.glob("C/folder/*.zip")]
file_paths = [extract_files(zf) for zf in zipped_files]

dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, header=None, sep=";") for f in file_paths]
df = pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)
```