# How to extract specific set of files in a zip file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, zip

I’ve a zip file say ‘test.zip’ and files name as ‘first.txt’ ,’first1.txt’ and ‘second.txt’ . I need to extract only files that start with word ‘first’ . How to do this in python ?

Comment: something similiar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56786321/read-multiple-csv-files-zipped-in-one-file

Comment: The solution in the question marked as duplicate can be adapted for files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over all files in zip archive and check filename before extracting:

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'r') as zp:
    files = zipfile.ZipFile.infolist(zp)
    for file in files:
        if file.filename.startswith('first'):
            with open(file.filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(zp.read(file.filename))
```