# Reading multiple csv in a zipe file with password

Tags: python, pandas, zip

I want to read some csv files, which are stored in a zip file, which is protected by a password. So the structure is:
1.zip: (a.csv, aa.csv, 12.csv ...)

and the password is: 'pass'.

I am try to following this question: [Python - the zipfile module doesn't seem to work with passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483138/python-the-zipfile-module-doesnt-seem-to-work-with-passwords)

and have a code with this question: [Read multiple csv files zipped in one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56786321/read-multiple-csv-files-zipped-in-one-file?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
for zip_file in glob.glob("C:/.../1.zip"):
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file)
    pw = 'pass'
    zf.setpassword(pw)
    dfs = [pd.read_csv(zf.open(f), sep="\t") for f in zf.namelist()]
    df = pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)
```

I get the error:

> TypeError: pwd: expected bytes, got str

What is the mistake?